# C project in NetBeans using GNU-C99 __flash qualifier causing "Unable to resolve identifier"

Tags: c, netbeans, qualifiers

I have an avr-gcc project in NetBeans 18 with the C/C++ plugin (not CPPLite Kit but the one from the NetBeans 8.2 Plugin Portal) which works really well besides the GNU-C99 `__flash` qualifier (and possibly also other GNU-C99 qualifiers).

Using the `__flash` qualifier causes an error marker, for example:

```
const __flash Font *unifont = &unifontFont;
```

The marker says "Unable to resolve identifier unifont."

Building the project in NetBeans works fine.

I have a "Tool Collection" in the `GNU` family with all the `avr-*` counterparts and in "Code Assistance -> C Compiler" I have "C Standard" `C99`.

Is there a way to tell the plugin that `__flash` is a valid qualifier or to use GNU-C99 by setting `-std=gnu99` somewhere?

Comment: it is avr specific and it will not work with standard compiler

Comment: `__flash` is a gcc qualifier and anyway, in "Tool Collection" I have avr-gcc.

Comment: it is named addres space not qualifier

Comment: Yes, but they are also called qualifier: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Named-Address-Spaces.html
`The __flash qualifier locates data in the .progmem.data section.`

Comment: @0___________:  It's a qualifier that specifies a named address space (in conrast to `progmem`, which is an avr-gcc specific attribute).